# <DevExpress.Spreadsheet>The more columns and rows, the slower the line is drawn

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Receive  as a parameter and draw a line to that size.

The more columns and rows, the slower the line is drawn.
Is there any way to improve it?

```
 private void Linestyle(DevExpress.Spreadsheet.Range rg1)
        {
        rg1.Borders.InsideHorizontalBorders.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Dotted;
        rg1.Borders.InsideVerticalBorders.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Dotted;
        rg1.Borders.TopBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
        rg1.Borders.LeftBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
        rg1.Borders.RightBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
        rg1.Borders.BottomBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
        rg1.Borders.InsideVerticalBorders.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
        rg1.Borders.InsideHorizontalBorders.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
        rg1.Borders.TopBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
        rg1.Borders.LeftBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
        rg1.Borders.RightBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
        rg1.Borders.BottomBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
        }
```

Comment: Have you made a ticket for this at devexpress ? I guess they can help you best with this

Comment: Have you tried it on another machine? Is it just slow on your machine?

Comment: How many is "more columns and rows"?

Answer (score 2):

Use `BeginUpdate()` before, and `EndUpdate()` after setting the borders.
Like this:

```
private void Linestyle(DevExpress.Spreadsheet.Range rg1)
{
    rg1.BeginUpdate();
    rg1.Borders.InsideHorizontalBorders.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Dotted;
    rg1.Borders.InsideVerticalBorders.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Dotted;
    rg1.Borders.TopBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
    rg1.Borders.LeftBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
    rg1.Borders.RightBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
    rg1.Borders.BottomBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
    rg1.Borders.InsideVerticalBorders.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rg1.Borders.InsideHorizontalBorders.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rg1.Borders.TopBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rg1.Borders.LeftBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rg1.Borders.RightBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rg1.Borders.BottomBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rg1.EndUpdate();
}
```

Performance on a 10x10 Range:

```
Without Begin/EndUpdate: ~5430ms
With Begin/EndUpdate: ~17ms
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the borders of a range of cells, call the [Range.BeginUpdateFormatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Spreadsheet.Range.BeginUpdateFormatting.method) method for this range, and use the Borders property of the returned Formatting object to access and modify the Borders collection. Then call the [Range.EndUpdateFormatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Spreadsheet.Range.EndUpdateFormatting.method) method to finalize the modification.

```
void SetupBorders(DevExpress.Spreadsheet.Range range) {
    Formatting rangeFormatting = range.BeginUpdateFormatting();
    Borders rangeBorders = rangeFormatting.Borders;
    rangeBorders.InsideHorizontalBorders.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Dotted;
    rangeBorders.InsideVerticalBorders.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Dotted;
    rangeBorders.TopBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
    rangeBorders.LeftBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
    rangeBorders.RightBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
    rangeBorders.BottomBorder.LineStyle = DevExpress.Spreadsheet.BorderLineStyle.Thick;
    rangeBorders.InsideVerticalBorders.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rangeBorders.InsideHorizontalBorders.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rangeBorders.TopBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rangeBorders.LeftBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rangeBorders.RightBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    rangeBorders.BottomBorder.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
    range.EndUpdateFormatting(rangeFormatting);
}
```

See the [How to: Add and Remove Cell Borders](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/15436/Controls-and-Libraries/Spreadsheet/Examples/Formatting-Cells/How-to-Add-and-Remove-Cell-Borders) for details.